# $\{ \mathcal N_x : x \in X \}$ acts as a neighbourhood system on $X$, where $\mathcal N_x$ is the family of all neighbourhoods of $x$ in $(X,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology

I have following exercise :

> If we have a topological space $(X,\tau)$ and for each $x \in X$ we define $$\mathcal N_x=\{N_x : N_x\supset O_x \ni x\text{ for some }O_x \in \tau\},$$ then $\{ \mathcal N_x : x \in X \}$ acts as neighbourhood system on $X$.

I don't know how to prove the following condition for being a neighbourhood system in the above case:

> Given $x\in X$ and $N_x \in \mathcal N_x$, there exists an $A_x\in \mathcal   N_x$ such that $A_x\subset N_x$ and $A_x \in \mathcal N_y$ for all $y \in A_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $N_x$ contains an open set $O_x$ which contains $x$. Take $A_x=O_x$. Of course $A_x\in\mathcal N_x$. But $O_x$ is an open set which contain each of its elements $y$, so we also may denote it $O_y$. Thus $N_x$, which contains $O_x=O_y$, which contains $y$, is a neighbourhood of $y$.